# How to pull a new-create file from server repository by svn?

Tags: linux, svn, centos

I've already install subversion in my centos server.
I created a new file named "test" in server's repository.How can I pull this file to my local repository?

What I've done:
I typed svn add test ,then svn commit test in command line,and then I updated in my PC's repository,but nothing happened.

I am a newbie.Thanks in advance!

Comment: You updated it in the local repository but where? On the server or on your pc?

Comment: I updated it in my pc@chris579

Comment: And you want to update it on the server?

Comment: I hava a file named "test" on the server,I want to update it to my pc's repository..@chris579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally.I know how the svn work.
I should create a svn repository in centos first, then add and commit that file to that repository ,and then checkout on PC.